# Why did the math preview in vscode fail when including physics package?

Tags: math-mode, preview, vscode

My code is written as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmicx,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
The state of the system is expressed as $\ket{\chi_1\ldots\chi_N}$
\end{document}
```

And it can't be previewed correctly. But when it is built, it will show the correct formula.
[image: The math preview shown]
[image: The correct result in the pdf built]
No warnings of errors occurred. How can I see the correct formula in the math preview? Thanks.

Comment: As long as you don't provide a full but minimal example others can test, everybodys guess

Comment: Note also that a lot of people here aren't Vig fans of the physics package

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but all packages but physics work in math preview on my computer, other examples in the physics package is essentially identical to what I have shown. Or I'll write a style file myself to contain all the commands I need.

Comment: We don't know what packages you are using or if you're ignoring compilation errors (which is actually a big problem). So if you want others to help provide a full minimal example others can test.

Comment: Unrelated hyperref should always be loaded as the last package (few exceptions) as it has to modify a lot of packages.

Comment: I changed the order but nothing happened to the math preview. And thank you for your advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126132/discussion-between-formic-and-daleif).

Comment: Which VScode extension are you using?